# How to use vendor theme in Android application

Tags: android, themes, vendor

I'm developing my "Hello, World" application for Android and came around something that annoys me.

The theme used for my app's `AlertDialog` isn't the same used for other such dialogs presented on the device. The device is a HTC Desire HD on which I've changed the theme, but I was expecting that standard UI elements (like `AlertDialog`) would somehow reflect the device theme. It's something that I'm missing or maybe a know problem with some vendors/models?

Here's my code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
confirm.setTitle("Delete")
       .setMessage("Really Delete?")
       .setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // ...
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
       .show();
```

And here's how the dialog looks like in different situations:

#### Device's `AlertDialog` with default theme (Messages app)

[image]

#### Device's `AlertDialog` with changed theme (Messages app)

[image]

#### My app's `AlertDialog` (with both default and changed theme)

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: After a few hours of playing with this device I can say that HTC probably used some custom components and didn't bother to reskin Android's ones. There are some built-in apps (Google apps) that seem to exhibit the same problem as my own app.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct.
HTC have most likley created customized dialogs for the HTC apps.